# GitLab CI : Passing artifact to another image on same stage

Tags: python, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, owasp

need some help. I generated a report from image as artifact and I want this to be pass to another image, here's the script

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
variables:
  website: "https://test.site/"
  scantype: "zap-baseline.py"
  report: "owasp-zap-report.html"

stages:
  - build

scan:
  stage: build
  image: owasp/zap2docker-stable
  allow_failure: true
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p /zap/wrk
  script:
    - pwd
    - ls
    - $scantype -t $website -m 1 -d -I -r $report
    - cp /zap/wrk/$report .
  artifacts:
    paths: [$report]

upload:
  stage: build
  dependencies:
    - scan
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  script:
    - ls
```

**Output**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.1.0 (76984217)
  on runner zgjy8gPC
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:04
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:20.04 ...
Pulling docker image ubuntu:20.04 ...
Using docker image sha256:3bc6e9f30f51d2bbf9307fc9d0bdfc30caa38cf4e3b05a714230f9a9b3381d84 for ubuntu:20.04 with digest ubuntu@sha256:af5efa9c28de78b754777af9b4d850112cad01899a5d37d2617bb94dc63a49aa ...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on runner-zgjy8gpc-project-1067-concurrent-0 via 1c8189df1d47...
Getting source from Git repository
00:03
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/test/test-owazp-pipeline/.git/
Checking out c90e0ea7 as cli...
Removing owasp-zap-report.html
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
Using docker image sha256:3bc6e9f30f51d2bbf9307fc9d0bdfc30caa38cf4e3b05a714230f9a9b3381d84 for ubuntu:20.04 with digest ubuntu@sha256:af5efa9c28de78b754777af9b4d850112cad01899a5d37d2617bb94dc63a49aa ...
$ ls
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

is there any key that I missed?

Comment: From https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/, it says "Subsequent jobs in later stages of the same pipeline can use artifacts." Sounds like jobs in the same stage cannot pass artifacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs and the keyword `needs`

Comment: The `needs` keyword only works with the jobs in different stages. For the jobs in the same stage, it doesn't work, as the artifact has not been created for that stage yet.